# Excel multplying various cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to solve a problem. Multiply a1*a2, if zero, multiply a1*a3. I tried using sumif(a1*a2),0,a1*a3 This totals both.

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(A1*A2 = 0, A1 * A3, A1 * A2)
```

The IF command has an argument in the first slot, what to do if the argument is true in the second slot, and what to do if the argument is false in third slot, where slots are separated by the commas.

```
=IF(ARGUMENT, WHAT TO DO IF TRUE, WHAT TO DO IF FALSE)
```